# NVIDIA 343 drive crashes X server

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, nvidia, x-server

In my Mint 17 install, I recently tried updating to the new proprietary NVIDIA 343 driver. When I reboot after install, X server fails to start. I can get a shell in recovery mode and tried running `nvidia-xconfig`, but no luck

The log file says:

```
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
Please consult The X.Org Foundation support
        at http://wiki.x.org
 for help
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: On Gentoo, I commonly fix this by rebuilding the kernel module.  The issue is there is no module in your modules directory in your kernel source.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: Reverse what you've done, and try [this forum post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=154932).

Comment: Tried that. The second time i ran the script i got an error saying nvidia driver is i compatible with nouveau driver and i need to disable it. Ive already done that.

Comment: Did you remove the nouveau module from the kernel and rebuild it?  Have you blacklisted the nouveau module in your autoload file if you can't rebuild your kernel?

Comment: I have no idea. I added a blacklist line to `/etc/default/grub` and i executed the uninstall of nouveau the forum post told me to. The first time i ran the install script i had no problem but now it says nouveau is installed and its incompatible.

Comment: When i boot the machine now, i get my login page, but when i try to log in the desktop never appears. I just get a black screen with a responsive mouse pointer.

Comment: 1. Grub has nothing to do w/ blacklisting modules. 2.  The NVIDIA installer should have blacklisted it for you.  3. Read the readme file included in the nvidia drivers you downloaded.  Make sure the version you downloaded supports your Card and your Kernel.

Comment: There was no readme. Its just a .run file. And it definitely is supported by my card. No clue how to even check what kernel I'm running. Its a standard Mint 17 install.

Comment: Maybe i should point this out: assume i know nothing about linux kernels and how to manipulate them.

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci | grep vga` and `uname -a` along with your computer type: Desktop, Laptop and a model.

Comment: `lspci | grep vga` yeilded nothing, `uname -a` yielded `Linux Mint-PC 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, and its a custom build PC

Comment: then ill need all of `lspci`

Comment: I cant really post it, because i cant get a desktop, so i cant paste it to pastebin. But if you meant `lspci | grep -i vga` i got `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] (rev a1)`

Comment: See answer, then we can remove these comments.

Answer (score 1):

Execute these commands in a terminal, in this order.  Step 4 adds the Xorg Developers PPA.  Once completed, tell me if step 7 installs the same version you downloaded.  Step 3 removes the offending module that is still loaded.  Step 5 removes the need for nomodeset on your kernel command line, so please remove whatever edit you made to `/etc/default/grub`

1. `sudo service mdm stop`
2. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current`
3. `sudo apt remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau libdrm-nouveau2`
4. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`
5. `sudo echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-blacklist.conf`
6. `sudo apt-get update`
7. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings`
8. `reboot`

---

**Update**

After installing Mint 17 as a VirtualBox Image, I have been experimenting with options, and believe these will solve the issue, in conjunction with the steps above.  [Nvidia-343 is the package name from the edgers PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers)

1. `sudo service mdm stop`
2. `sudo apt-get purge nouveau*`
3. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current`
4. `sudo apt-get-install nvidia-343`

Comment: Well my whole system is broken now, so for the 4th time since trying to install this driver, i have to do a complete reinstall of Mint. Ill report back once its done

Comment: But as an aside, when i previously installed the drivers from the repo I've never been able to get newer than 340. The 340 drivers lag horribly for me so i was hoping 343 might fix it. I'm sure I'm just kidding myself

Comment: The whole system is not broken.  You've just removed the Xorg driver.  Do the commands I gave in a plain terminal.  Press Ctl + Alt + F2 to login to a plain terminal.  Once you get the 340 drivers installed properly, we will update them to 343.

Comment: I tried booting, and i now cant get a terminal. After the login screen i have 2 options: login, which yields a black screen with a responsive mouse, or CTRL+ALT+F1, which yields a black screen with an unresponsive cursor. I've already started the reinstall. Can't hurt anyway.

Comment: While we wait, does step 3 have to be run as sudo?

Comment: OK, for future reference Ctrl + Alt + Fn where n is 2 thru 6 will give you a login, 7 and 8 will give you the current X Server, and some systems use 9 -12 for debug and status messages.  F1 will be black because it was controlled by the bootup process that failed, and F7 will behave as you describe because your driver isn't correct, and yes, I'll update Step 3

Comment: Also, should i start from the forum post or from this answer on the new install?

Comment: Start at this post.  We'll use that forum post to get from 340 to 343.  Step 2 may report nothing to purge.

Comment: Ok. I ran these commands and have the same issue. The desktop doesn't load. CTRL+ALT+F2 does give me a terminal. What's next?

Comment: Did they all run successfully?  Add `sudo nvidia-xconfig`

Comment: The only exception is there was no `libdrm-nouveau1`, but there was a `libdrm-nouveau2`, so i purged that. Did i screw it up?

Comment: After `nvidia-xconfig`, i still get no desktop.

Comment: Type `sudo service mdm stop && startx`  If you get a desktop, I'll update my post.

Comment: `startx` froze after `* Restoring resolver state...              [ OK ]`

Comment: I rebooted and tried it again. No desktop. I have to get ready for work though so ill just leave it and see if it eventually boots. Random question: could it be a cinnamon issue? x seems to be working, since i get a login page and no errors, just no desktop. Should i try installing MATE?

Comment: Let me put a Mint install in a virtualbox while  you're at work.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: Still no luck. With the new suggestions. I'm gonna give Mate a try. See what happens

Comment: Here's a new development: i installed nvidia-343, and executed `sudo startx`. It froze at `Restoring resolver state`, so i hit CTRL+ALT+PrtScn+K, and got an error saying "API Mismatch: the client has the version 343.22, but this kernel module has the version 304.123. Please make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver components have the same version"

Comment: So i ran through it again. After reboot, MATE gave me a desktop, but driver manager said i was still using nouveau. I tried switching to nvidia, and after several tries it just kept reverting to nouveau. Finally i rebooted, and ended up with an 800x600 login screen, and I cant select and environment. When i try to login i get an error saying `Failed to load session "cinnamon"`, and it kicks me back to a login screen

Comment: After reinstalling `mint-meta-cinnamon` (which uninstalled `nvidia-343`), i can boot into Cinnamon and select the 331 driver, but cant select 340 (it just reverts to whatever was selected before). I'm starting to wonder if this is worth it. I think I'm just destined to never have a working piece of technology

Comment: Do you mind experimenting?  What are your Update Settings on.  Default should be 2.  Try 4.  Download the newest kernel, reboot and reinstall `nvidia-343`

Comment: No luck with the newest kernel. Still getting a black screen on cinnamon, then after installing mate, mate gives a desktop and cinnamon crashes

Comment: Is mate using nouveau or nvidia?

Comment: At first, nouveau, but managed to switch over to nvidia 340. 343 still doesn't show up in driver manager. After reinstalling cinnamon, i can get into cinnamon in 340.

Comment: In my case I needed to preinstall `libwayland-egl` before the nvidia driver install.